# getting a row using xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

Anyone know how to reference a given row of newSheet shown below

```
import xlwt
outFile = xlwt.Workbook()
newSheet = outFile.add_sheet('Sheet 1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
#Write a bunch of data to newSheet
```

For example I want to reference the first row so I can find which column has a certain header.

EDIT: I'd like to be to run this code somehow

```
newSheet.col(firstRow.index('some pattern')).width = 3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlwt`is only for writing Excel files. Use `xlrd` for reading.
If you have written the file yourself should know what you wrote where. 
Just remember in a dict or list where you wrote your header.